# Add ambient light sensor into cordova-2.5.0.js - phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have to develop an Android application using phongap that retrieves the sensors data from the device.

One of the sensors I have to listen to is the ambient light sensor. This sensor has no implementation in phoneGap, so I have to add it as a plugin to PhoneGap.

I know how to add plugin and I know how to access the ALS data from Java - but in order to be sure that I am implementing it well I want to implement it as PhoneGap implements other sensors like Accelerometer. Therefor I wrote a `ALSManager` class in java that I implemented as I found the Accelerometer was implemented here:

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/AccelListener.java

and added lightSensor and lightValues modules like the acceleromter and acceleration modules.

But when I run this application I got following error message:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'getCurrentLight'

(and in the lightSensor module I have getCurrentLight method).

does any one can please suggest me what I am missing? or what do I have to do?

Thanks in advance,

---

The code I added in the cordova-2.5.0.js. Let me know if it's not enough:

```
    // file: lib/common/plugin/LightValues.js
define("cordova/plugin/LightValues", function(require, exports, module) {

var Acceleration = function(lux, timestamp) {
    this.lux = lux;
    this.timestamp = timestamp || (new Date()).getTime();
};

module.exports = LightValues;

});
// file: lib/common/plugin/lightSensor.js
define("cordova/plugin/lightSensor", function(require, exports, module) {

/**
 * This class provides access to device accelerometer data.
 * @constructor
 */
var argscheck = require('cordova/argscheck'),
    utils = require("cordova/utils"),
    exec = require("cordova/exec"),
    LightValues = require('cordova/plugin/LightValues');

// Is the accel sensor running?
var running = false;

// Keeps reference to watchAcceleration calls.
var timers = {};

// Array of listeners; used to keep track of when we should call start and stop.
var listeners = [];

// Last returned acceleration object from native
var light = null;

// Tells native to start.
function start() {
    exec(function(a) {
        var tempListeners = listeners.slice(0);
        light = new LightValues(a.lux, a.timestamp);
        for (var i = 0, l = tempListeners.length; i < l; i++) {
            tempListeners[i].win(light);
        }
    }, function(e) {
        var tempListeners = listeners.slice(0);
        for (var i = 0, l = tempListeners.length; i < l; i++) {
            tempListeners[i].fail(e);
        }
    }, "Light", "start", []);
    running = true;
}

// Tells native to stop.
function stop() {
    exec(null, null, "Light", "stop", []);
    running = false;
}

// Adds a callback pair to the listeners array
function createCallbackPair(win, fail) {
    return {win:win, fail:fail};
}

// Removes a win/fail listener pair from the listeners array
function removeListeners(l) {
    var idx = listeners.indexOf(l);
    if (idx > -1) {
        listeners.splice(idx, 1);
        if (listeners.length === 0) {
            stop();
        }
    }
}

var lightSensor = {
    /**
     * Asynchronously acquires the current acceleration.
     *
     * @param {Function} successCallback    The function to call when the acceleration data is available
     * @param {Function} errorCallback      The function to call when there is an error getting the acceleration data. (OPTIONAL)
     * @param {AccelerationOptions} options The options for getting the accelerometer data such as timeout. (OPTIONAL)
     */
    getCurrentLight: function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
        //argscheck.checkArgs('fFO', 'lightSensor.getCurrentLight', arguments);

        var p;
        var win = function(a) {
            removeListeners(p);
            successCallback(a);
        };
        var fail = function(e) {
            removeListeners(p);
            errorCallback && errorCallback(e);
        };

        p = createCallbackPair(win, fail);
        listeners.push(p);

        if (!running) {
            start();
        }
    },

    /**
     * Asynchronously acquires the acceleration repeatedly at a given interval.
     *
     * @param {Function} successCallback    The function to call each time the acceleration data is available
     * @param {Function} errorCallback      The function to call when there is an error getting the acceleration data. (OPTIONAL)
     * @param {AccelerationOptions} options The options for getting the accelerometer data such as timeout. (OPTIONAL)
     * @return String                       The watch id that must be passed to #clearWatch to stop watching.
     */
    watchLight: function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
        //argscheck.checkArgs('fFO', 'lightSensor.watchLight', arguments);
        // Default interval (10 sec)
        var frequency = (options && options.frequency && typeof options.frequency == 'number') ? options.frequency : 10000;

        // Keep reference to watch id, and report accel readings as often as defined in frequency
        var id = utils.createUUID();

        var p = createCallbackPair(function(){}, function(e) {
            removeListeners(p);
            errorCallback && errorCallback(e);
        });
        listeners.push(p);

        timers[id] = {
            timer:window.setInterval(function() {
                if (light) {
                    successCallback(light);
                }
            }, frequency),
            listeners:p
        };

        if (running) {
            // If we're already running then immediately invoke the success callback
            // but only if we have retrieved a value, sample code does not check for null ...
            if (light) {
                successCallback(light);
            }
        } else {
            start();
        }

        return id;
    },

    /**
     * Clears the specified accelerometer watch.
     *
     * @param {String} id       The id of the watch returned from #watchAcceleration.
     */
    clearWatch: function(id) {
        // Stop javascript timer & remove from timer list
        if (id && timers[id]) {
            window.clearInterval(timers[id].timer);
            removeListeners(timers[id].listeners);
            delete timers[id];
        }
    }
};

module.exports = lightSensor;

});
```

Comment: Can you post your config.xml and the javascript file? It sounds like the mapping from javascript to java is wrong.

Comment: can you please share your e-mail address with me? I will send you the files? they are too long...

Comment: Well I would prefer that we keep the discussion here so that anybody else that stumbles upon this question can get the answers. You can use services like http://www.pastebucket.com/ to share code, or you could create an account on github and fork cordova-android and share the code there. You probably also don't need to post the entire file, just the part where you add the javascript side of the plugin to the page and the config.xml where you list out the plugin.

Comment: @MBillau: plaese see the editing above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe the problem is that you are adding your plugin code to `cordova-2.5.0.js` file. Instead what you should do is create a standalone JS file for each of your JavaScript files and then `cordova.require()` those files in the HTML page where you want to use that functionality.

So, create `LightValues.js` and `LightSensor.js` as separate files somewhere in your www folder. Then in your HTML file, make sure to include the JS file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-lightSensor.JS-file">` (You'd only need to include this one file since it require()s the second one.)

Next, in `deviceReady()` function, you can call the light sensor with `var lightSensor = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/lightSensor")`. Notice that the **cordova/plugin/lightSensor** is not the path to the JS file but the name of it module that you declared in the `define()` section when you wrote the plugin.

After this you should be able to call lightSensor.getCurrentLight(). If you `console.log(lightSensor)` you would expect to see all of the available methods that you wrote.

Note that I'm not positive that `cordova.require` and `cordova.define` work in cordova-2.5. I'd hope that they do but [this page sort of suggests it may not be supported until 2.6](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/wiki/Wrapping-your-Plugin%27s-JavaScript). If you are having problems after splitting the files out, maybe it is because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just developed a light sensor plugin and fortunately succeed. I have just read the code above and found some small mistakes about identifier e.g "var Acceleration = function(lux, timestamp)" the variable should be LightValues instead of Acceleration. So please check the code first to void some essential mistakes. Then, I first use "lux" as the name of the variable but I got an undefined value of light when debugging the program. So I change "lux" into "x" and it did work!

There are 6 files should be paid attention to: the "LightListener.java", "LightValues.js", "LightSensor.js","cordova_plugin.js", "index.html" and "config.xml". If you configure all the 6 files, the program should work.